# Code syntax highlighting in my Rails 4.0.4 app using Redcarpet & Pygments.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pygments, redcarpet, pygmentize

## The objective

I am trying to render markdown documentation with snippets of code in it, and I'd like to highlight the syntax like on Github or BitBucket.

### My Environment

- Rails 4.0.4
- Ruby 2.1.1

### In my gemfile

```
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'redcarpet' # markdown
gem 'rdiscount'
gem 'pygments.rb', '~> 0.5.4'
```

### Initializer

I have tried this, but my snippets of code don't get highlighted:

```
module Haml::Filters

  remove_filter("Markdown") #remove the existing Markdown filter

  module Markdown

    include Haml::Filters::Base

    class HTMLwithPygments < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
      def block_code(code, language)
        Pygments.highlight(code, lexer: language)
      end
    end


    def render(text)
      #Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new(prettify: true), fenced_code_blocks: true).render(text)
      Redcarpet::Markdown.new(HTMLwithPygments, fenced_code_blocks: true).render(text)
    end

  end
end
```

tested with this simple YAML

```
 hello:
    world: "hey"
```

the code generated looks right (?)

```
<div class="highlight">
   <pre>  
    <span class="l-Scalar-Plain">hello</span><span class="p-Indicator">:</span>
    <span class="l-Scalar-Plain">world</span><span class="p-Indicator">:</span> 
    <span class="s">"hey"</span>
    </pre>
</div>
```

but it's plain grey, not highlighted

Do I need to install any CSS files for these classes to render properly??

Any suggestion?

Comment: see if this [blog post](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/272-markdown-with-redcarpet) helps you.

Comment: I actually did my home work and tried most of the tutorial resource out there, but considering that I am using Rails .4.0.4, there might be a little hitch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I fixed it:

```
bash
$ pygmentize -S default -f html > style.css
```

and added this file to my *css* folder.